# How to perform S3 to BigQuery using Airflow?

Tags: airflow

Currently there is no [S3ToBigQuery operator](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2902).

My choices are:

1. Use the [S3ToGoogleCloudStorageOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/120f4856cdea5134971c4c4a239ddbfdc80db77e/airflow/contrib/operators/s3_to_gcs_operator.py)  and then use the `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator`

   This is not something i'm eager to do. This means paying double for storage. Even if removing the file from either one of the storage that still involves payment.
2. Download the file from `S3` to local file system and load it to BigQuery from file system - However there is no `S3DownloadOperator` This means writing the whole process from scratch without Airflow involvement. This misses the point of using Airflow.

Is there another option? What would you suggest to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with. 
This should be converted to a S3toLocalFile Operator.

```
def download_from_s3(**kwargs):
    hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='project-s3')    

    result = hook.read_key(bucket_name='stage-project-metrics',
                           key='{}.csv'.format(kwargs['ds']))

    if not result:
        logging.info('no data found')
    else:
        outfile = '{}project{}.csv'.format(Variable.get("data_directory"),kwargs['ds'])

        f=open(outfile,'w+')
        f.write(result)
        f.close()

    return result
```

Comment: Why do  you assume the file is csv?

Comment: In my case I only want to read the csv files for a given ds.  So the key (s3 filename) would end up being something like 2018-09-18.csv.  For other use cases just change the way the key value is constructed to match the file(s) you want to pickup in the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

If the first option is cost restrictive, you could just use the `S3Hook` [to download the file](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.py#L177) through the PythonOperator:

```
from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3Hook
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3Hook
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 1),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0
}
def download_from_s3(**kwargs):


    hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='s3_conn')

    hook.read_key(bucket_name='workflows-dev',
                   key='test_data.csv')

dag = DAG('s3_download',
          schedule_interval='@daily',
          default_args=default_args,
          catchup=False)

with dag:
download_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id='download_data',
        python_callable=download_from_s3,
        provide_context=True
    )
```

Comment: where do I specify where to save the file? can this hook support downloading a folder that contains more than 1 file? how then I load the files to BigQuery I don't see a load file from file system?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do instead is use `S3ToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` and then use `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` with an `external_table` table flag i.e pass `external_table =True`.

This will create an external data that points to GCS location and doesn't store your data in BigQuery but you can still query it.

Comment: This is a nice hack , could be use full for others but I need to solve it without using external table. I need the data to actually be saved on BigQuery. I need to use partitions etc...