# GCP DataTransferServiceClient, how to set up the procedure

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

```
    # This snippet has been automatically generated and should be regarded as a
# code template only.
# It will require modifications to work:
# - It may require correct/in-range values for request initialization.
# - It may require specifying regional endpoints when creating the service
#   client as shown in:
#   https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/client_options.html
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer_v1

def sample_start_manual_transfer_runs():
    # Create a client
    client = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.DataTransferServiceClient()

    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.StartManualTransferRunsRequest(
    )

    # Make the request
    response = client.start_manual_transfer_runs(request=request)

    # Handle the response
    print(response)
```

I am trying to write a script that manually triggers s3 to bigquery. However, I am unsure of how to integrate other types and functions provided from DataTransferServiceClient.
For example, how do I integrate [transfer_config](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquerydatatransfer/latest/google.cloud.bigquery_datatransfer_v1.types.TransferConfig) into the script above. Also, I am not quite sure how to get config_id from transfer_config once I have it.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? Are you trying to transfer data from amazon s3 to bigquery?

Comment: @kiranmathew Transfering data from aws s3 to bigquery. data is in csv format, working from an instance up on aws, (both aws and gcp credentials have been granted). going to put this code inside airflow so that it can trigger the data transfer that is dependent to other tasks.

Comment: Does this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149840/) help you?